# Salesforce integration with Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: tfs, salesforce, azure-devops, salesforce-service-cloud

I have been looking into **Salesforce** and **Team Foundation 2013** integration lately. Is there any addins or solution to do so?

Comment: What kind of integration are we talking about? What have you tried? What are your expectations?

Comment: Exporting the Cases from Salesforce as a TFS item so they can end up in the backlog for the development team. I haven't started on anything just researching if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'n not aware of an existing system that does this. [TFS has a well documented client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.aspx), so it should be relatively [easy to do a one-way export to TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322.aspx). For more "automatic" syncs you can look at the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

For publishing changes from TFS back to Salesforce, you could look at the same TFS Integration Platform, or do a server side integration through an [ISubscriber plugin](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/assafstone/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions/) in-process in the TFS server or [registering a SOAP event](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/how-to-use-wcf-to-subscribe-to-the-tfs-2010-event-service-rolling-up-hours.aspx) for a more  decoupled solution.

I do not have any knowledge about the Salesforce api model, but I suppose that, it being a cloud product, they provide a webservice or a REST API which you can talk to.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner approach would be a real time sync between the two systems.
For that you can use on the salesforce side Outbound Messaging and a Workflow rule. You basically define a rule to trigger a message, and the objects and fields you will send in this SOAP message as well as the URL of the webservice endpoint handling it. Your webservice endpoint will be queuing these messages to a common messaging queue used by your Sync Service.
On the TFS side you can create a plug in to handle the workitemchanged event for your particular workitem, so every time your workitem change you queue that workitemchanged event object to the common messaging queue used in the Sync.

With the above in place you create a sync service that get the messages and update either system.

For example:
[Something like this](http://autocrony.com/TFS/tfs_salesforce_sync.jpg)